# using Regular Expression how to get (16.00 + 28.66 = 44.66) as 44.66 and (99) as 99

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Im using `regular expression` to get values such as `(16.00 + 28.66 = 44.66)` as `44.66 ,(26.00) as 26.00`

I have trouble to display data when its `just(99)` as `99` without any decimal.

I have used the below code to till now

```
string amount = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        Regex regex = new Regex("(\\d+\\.\\d{2})(?=\\))", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
   | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
   | RegexOptions.Compiled
   );
```

Someone please tell me how can i display a value without any decimal..

`Eg-(99) as 99`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your drop down list contain values like these?

```
    (20.01 + 20.01 = 40.02)
    (40.02)
    (40)
```

If yes, you can try this Regular Expression

```
    (\\d+(\\.\\d{2})?)(?=\\))
```

Comment: Thanks so much!Im new to regx and dont know how to work with it.thanks again:)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without *Regex* using ToString format, you can fix the number of decimal places. The `99` will be `99.00`. You can read more about custom numeric formats over [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string formatedNum = double.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text).ToString(".00");
```

> The "0" custom format specifier serves as a zero-placeholder symbol.
>   If the value that is being formatted has a digit in the position where
>   the zero appears in the format string, that digit is copied to the
>   result string; otherwise, a zero appears in the result string. The
>   position of the leftmost zero before the decimal point and the
>   rightmost zero after the decimal point determines the range of digits
>   that are always present in the result string, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Specifier0).